# How to turn a column having empty spaces and NAs into a factor? and can we turn character into numeric?

Tags: r

My question is "convert the `route` column to a factor to save space" where a route is a character

I tried

```
drug<-as.factor(drug$route)
```

but this didn't help. I am not sure if we can turn the character in numeric to save space

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addNA` from base R.

```
x <- c("A", "B", "B", NA, NA)
x <- as.factor(as.character(x))

> levels(x)
[1] "A" "B"

x <- addNA(x)
levels(x)

> levels(x)
[1] "A" "B" NA
```